# c# How to enum all the letters (Chars) of the alphabet for the system language?

Tags: c#, keyboard

How to enum all the letters (Chars) of the alphabet for the system language?
Need for the virtual keyboard.
Languages ​​may be different, and Chinese and Russian, etc.

Comment: Note that some languages such as Chinese, do not have alphabets. Also this doesn't take into account symbols that are typically available. You really need a keyboard layout, not an alphabet.

Comment: Sounds to me you are committing to a project without having any clue what real keyboards look like.  A Chinese one doesn't have 40000 keys.  Best to avoid re-inventing that wheel, operating systems already have a virtual keyboard.  Osk.exe on Windows for example.

Comment: Ineed to make the virtual keyboard on the similarity of the standard in the laptop.
The Chinese have a laptop too, 40,000 keys? ;)

Comment: Is there a way of getting the currently active keyboard layout? I mean with the actual letters, not the virtual ones?